# Wrong DNS for just one site on development machine

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-vista, tcpip

www.superyoink.de is my clients' website. I can access it from any machine except my development one.

If I ping it on my development machine, I get 80.67.28.107 - this is wrong.

My laptop, next to me, is able to resolve it correctly.

I have tried putting correct address into hosts like so:

93.187.232.191 www.superyoink.de

Still resolves to wrong address.

I can enter bogus DNS server addresses so nothing works.  But www.superyoink.de still resolves to 80.67.28.107.

Rebooted, did ipconfig /flushdns nothing seems to work.

I run 32 bit Vista.  My impression is that it has stored the wrong dns resolution somewhere and is not even trying the DNS servers.  But where?  Help please!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Filter for ping.exe (after a ipconfig /flushdns). Search the output for clause.

**Before update:**Put other address in your host file. To make sure that you are viewing the correct file.

124.23.2.3 akjsdf.com

and ping it.

Comment: You nailed it - when I searched for hosts, Vista showed a backup file in an indexed location.  The active file had wrong address written in.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you run a nslookup what do you get?

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>nslookup contoso.com
Server:  scant2.cannla.local
Address:  192.168.1.20

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    contoso.com
Addresses:  207.46.232.182
          207.46.197.32
```

what if you run nslookup with an alternative dns server?

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>nslookup contoso.com 203.109.252.42
Server:  tig-nz-akl-ns-42.ihug.net
Address:  203.109.252.42

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    contoso.com
Addresses:  207.46.232.182
          207.46.197.32
```

that should help find the answer

Comment: Server:  dns.lax1.speakeasy.net
Address:  64.81.45.2

Then when i try ping:
Pinging www.superyoink.de [80.67.28.107] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 80.67.28.107: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=57

Totally wrogn address.